# Operator norm on non-unit ball

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $T:X \to Y$ is a bounded linear operator with $X$ and $Y$ being vector spaces.  Show that if we define
$$
\|T\|_1 = \sup_{x \in B(0,1)} \|Tx\|
$$
and for a fixed $r > 0$,
$$
\|T\|_2 = \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} \|Tx\|,
$$
then $\|T\|_2 = r \|T\|_1$.

I already showed
\begin{align}
\|T\|_2 &= \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} \left( \|x\| \left\|T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\| \right) \\
&\le \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} \|x\| \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} \left\|T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right\| \\
&= r \sup_{\|y\|=1} \|Ty\| = r \|T\|_1.
\end{align}
However, I'm stuck with the other inequality: $\|T\|_2 \ge r \|T\|_1$.

I'm aware that there is an inequality $\sup (ab) \ge \sup a \cdot \sup b$, but I doubt to apply its proof here because $a = \|x\|$ and $b = \left\|T\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right) \right\|$ in my problem are dependent.

Can someone please help me show the other inequality?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as

$$
\|T\|_2 = \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} ||T(x)|| = \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} r ||T(x/r)|| =  r \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} ||T(x/r)|| = r \sup_{y \in B(0,1)} ||T(y)|| = r ||T||_1
$$

The equality $ r \sup_{x \in B(0,r)} ||T(x/r)|| = r \sup_{y \in B(0,1)} ||T(y)||$ is simply due to the fact that the sets $\{x/r: x \in B(0,r)\}$ and $\{y: y \in B(0,1)\}$ are equal.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It's so simple! Maybe I was overthinking.